# group by column and identify key rows

Tags: r, matrix, group-by, dplyr

I divide the problem into two:

Problem1:
I have a list(list1) of matrices(Mat1, Mat2). Each matrix has the same dimensions but different elements. For each matrix I need to group the data by "number" and then move to "score". I need to identify the row with the maximum score. I want to store this row number in a list titled output1. I want to store all other row numbers in a list titled output2.Important: I do not want to store the row itself. I want to store the **row number**

Problem2: Is the same as problem 1. However, in this case I group the data by number and then move to "score" and find the rows with the top two numbers.

Setup:

```
set.seed(4)
Mat1 <- data.frame(matrix(nrow=508, ncol =4))
Mat1[,1] <- c(rep(1,20), rep(NA, 508-20))
Mat1[1:20,2:4] <- rnorm(20*3,0,1)


Mat2 <- data.frame(matrix(nrow=508, ncol =4))
Mat2[,1] <- c(rep(c(1,2,3,4,5),5), rep(NA, 508-25))
Mat2[1:30,2:4] <- rnorm(30*3,0,1)


colnames(Mat1)[1:2] = colnames(Mat2)[1:2] = c("number", "score")
list1 <- list(Mat1, Mat2)


Mat1
    number       score         X3          X4
1        1  0.21675486  1.5408150  1.34370863
2        1 -0.54249257  0.1651690  0.18153538
3        1  0.89114465  1.3076224  1.29251234
4        1  0.59598058  1.2882569 -1.68804858
5        1  1.63561800  0.5928969 -0.82099358
6        1  0.68927544 -0.2829437 -0.86214614
7        1 -1.28124663  1.2558840  0.09884369
8        1 -0.21314452  0.9098392 -0.37565514
9        1  1.89653987 -0.9280281  0.72390416
10       1  1.77686321  1.2401808 -1.79738202
11       1  0.56660450  0.1534642 -0.66374314
12       1  0.01571945  1.0519326 -0.62372649
13       1  0.38305734 -0.7542112 -0.07963243
14       1 -0.04513712 -1.4821891  0.43562476
15       1  0.03435191  0.8611319  1.97090097
16       1  0.16902677 -0.4045198 -0.59675867
17       1  1.16502684 -0.2274054 -0.55250721
18       1 -0.04420400  0.9340962  0.69596663
19       1 -0.10036844 -0.4658959 -0.15566396
20       1 -0.28344457 -0.6375435  1.34889820
```

So Mat 1 has one group corresponding to number =1. I want to group data by "number" and identify the row with the maximum value (For Mat1 this would be row 9). I then want to store the number 9 in a list titled Output1. Output2[[1]] would then consist of 507 (508-1) elements and hence, all row numbers except row number 9.

I then want to repeat this process for Mat2. Output1[[2]] should consist of elements (as "number" has 5 groups. number can = 1,2,3,4 or 5.)

I want to repeat this process for all matrices in the set. In my application i have a very large number of matrices in the set.

Comment: for Problem1 ```output1 <- lapply(list1,. %>% group_by(`number`) %>% slice(which.max(`score`)))``` is close. However it stores actual rows and treats NA as a factor to group by (which should not be the case)

Comment: Do you want to remove all `NA` values from `Output1` as well as `Output2` ?

Comment: @RonakShah to clarify: Output1[[1]] should have 1 element (No NAs). Output1[[2]] should have 5 elements (No NAs). Output2[[1]] should have 507 elements (No NAs), Output2[[2]] should have 508-5 elements (No NAs). Is this clear?

Comment: yes but if you check your reproducible example you have got all `NA` values from row 21 onwards till 508 in 1st matrix. Check `list1[[1]][21:30, ]` for first 10. I am no sure how you will get `Output2[[1]]` with 507 elements and no `NA`s.

Comment: @RonakShah it doesn't matter. Output1[[1]] would consist of the number 9. Output2[[1]] would be all numbers 1:508 excluding 9.

Comment: @RonakShah That code stored the actual rows of data. This time i only want the 'row number'. Not the whole row stored.

Comment: adapting first comment and avoiding grouping by number, this is another approximation : `output1 <- lapply(list1,. %>% rownames_to_column() %>% slice(which.max(score)) %>% select(rowname))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grouping and subsetting is easily done with `data.table`.

```
library(data.table)

lapply(list1, function(x) {

    setDT(x)

    # add row numbers to grouped data.table
    x[, rownum := .I]

    # add a coulmn indicating row(s) with max score for each group
    x[, maxscore := (score==max(score)), by=number]

    # exclude NAs

    maxrows <- x[maxscore==TRUE][!is.na(number)]
    otherrows <- x[maxscore==FALSE]

    # get those row numbers
    list(
        output1 = maxrows$rownum,
        output2 = otherrows$rownum
    )
})
```

Note couple of things:

- if you have the same top score appearing twice within a group, this way you will get all the rows where this value appears - rather, if you only ordered the grouped rows and selected the first one, you'd miss out on possible other rows with the same max score value
- you get output1 and output2 in one go - to me this makes more sense than looping twice - you can later select whichever elements you want from the output, and also get them as two separate lists, if that's what you need

Answer (score 2):

We can use `dplyr` and `purrr` to get row indices in `output1` and `output2`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

output1 <- map(list1, ~ .x %>% na.omit %>%
                        mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
                        group_by(number) %>% 
                        summarise(max = row[which.max(score)]) %>% 
                        pull(max))


output2 <- map2(map(list1, ~seq_len(nrow(.x))), output1, setdiff)
```